# How to add | (pipe) between list with jquery

Tags: jquery

The following is created dynamically.

```
<div id="footermenu">
<ul><li><a href="Nettbutikk.asp" title="" class="topactive">Nettbutikk</a></li>
<li><a href="Infosenter.asp" title="" class="">Infosenter</a></li>
<li><a href="Kontakt_oss.asp" title="" class="">Kontakt oss</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

With this text:

```
Nettbutikk Infosenter Koatakt oss
```

I'd like to add | between to make like this.

```
Nettbutikk | Infosenter | Koatakt oss
```

Nettbutikk etc will be changed in future, so I thought I should use li:first and li:nth-child(2).

I tried this but it gives an error telling:

> TypeError: $("#footermenu ul li:first") is null { message="$("#footermenu ul li:first") is null",  more...}
>
> ```
> $("#footermenu ul li:first").append(' | ');
> ```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just use `$("#footermenu ul li:not(:last)")`?

Comment: This looks like it was solved by including jQuery, so is not likely to be useful for future readers. It can be closed under the official reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/cm8fX/). Are you sure you're including jQuery properly?